# Какой контент входит в размер Record Size Limit (TLS 1.3)

Tags: tls

Читаю RFC и никак не могу понять какой максимальный размер пользовательских данных можно уместить в Record TLS 1.3...
В [спецификации](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8449) указан лимит `(1 << 14) + 1` (16385 байт). Но у нас ещё есть заголовок записи длиной в 5 байт, 1 байт для определения типа payload-а в конце сообщения, и 16 байт `gcm_auth_tag`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот эти 5 + 1 + 16 входят в лимит 16385? Или входят только 1 + 16, или только 1, или ничего не входит и весь лимит расчитан под данные приложения? Пишу свою реализацию и надо понимать какой максимальный буффер выделять под record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лимит в 16384 байтов относится к открытому тексту ([RFC 8446, стр. 79](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#page-79)). Реализация может добавлять к открытому тексту выравнивание произвольной длины и необходимые для алгоритма шифрования дополнительные данные. Итоговый размер записи не может превышать 2^14 + 256 байтов ([RFC 8446, стр. 81](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#page-81))

> length:  The length (in bytes) of the following
> TLSCiphertext.encrypted_record, which is the sum of the lengths of
> the **content** and the **padding**, plus one for the **inner content type**,
> plus any **expansion** added by the AEAD algorithm.  The length
> MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 256 bytes.

Comment: Благодарю. Ну, зачитался, запутался ))